# Json_decode desde CURL

Tags: php

recibo este json desde un llamado CURL y necesito tomar algunos datos, y no logro tomar por el email,first_name, etc
uso el json_encode con y sin true y no logro tomar ningun dato, obtengo el error
como levanto el dato que necesite?

este resultado lo devuelve el curl y ya tiene el json en el encabezado (content-type)

El error es `PHP Notice:  Undefined index: bank_accounts`

El codigo que uso es el siguiente:

```
$curl = curl_init();    
$url='https://miurl.com';
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Bearer 245622522q3fsa235','Content-Type:application/json'));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
$Datos=curl_exec($curl);                    
$DatosJson=json_decode($Datos,true);            

#La siguientes lines son para ver cual me extrae los datos
echo $DatosJson['data']['data']['bank_accounts']['email'];  
echo $DatosJson->data->data->bank_accounts->email;

curl_close($curl);
```

este es el json que el curl devuelve

```
{
   "data": {
       "data": [
           {
               "legder_balance": "0.00",
               "available_balance": "0.00",
               "bank_accounts": [
                   {
                       "metadata": "{}",
                       "provider": {
                           "bank_code": "053",
                           "bank_name": "Providus",
                           "id": "providus",
                           "default": true
                       },
                       "first_name": "Victor",
                       "last_name": "Alade",
                       "email": "mail@gmail.com",
                       "is_permanent": true,
                       "account_ref": "4aebbcaa1a41",
                       "business_id": "548fc51fe7df",
                       "created_at": "2021-08-09T12:06:19.000Z",
                       "status": "active",
                       "account_name": "MERCHANT(Victor Alade)",
                       "account_number": "9977633837",
                       "bvn": "12345678923"
                   }
               ],
               "status": "active",
               "wallet_ref": "8fc531bb545e6",
               "business_id": "548fc51fe7df",
               "created_at": "2021-08-09T12:06:19.000Z",
               "currency": "AR"
           }
       ],
       "meta": {
           "page": 1,
           "limit": 10,
           "previousPage": false,
           "nextPage": false,
           "pageCount": 1,
           "total": 1
       }
   },
   "errors": {},
   "message": "Request successful"
}
```

Comment: ¿Y qué has intentado? Por favor, muéstranos tu código...

Comment: hola, estoy intentando asi:
$Datos=curl_exec($curl);     
$DatosJson=json_decode($Datos,true);   
echo $DatosJson['data']['data']['bank_accounts']['email'];
Tambien $DatosJson->data->data->bank_accounts->email;

Comment: Edita la pregunta e incluye el código del comentario y el error que obtienes

Comment: Editada la pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, prueba con:

```
echo $DatosJson['data']['data'][0]['bank_accounts'][0]['email'];
```

Esto te sucede porque `json_decode()` convierte el JSON en un array con esta estructura:

```
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [legder_balance] => 0.00
                            [available_balance] => 0.00
                            [bank_accounts] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [metadata] => {}
                                            [provider] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [bank_code] => 053
```

Puedes comprobarlo con:

```
echo '<pre>'.print_r($DatosJson,true).'</pre>';
```

Espero que te haya resultado de ayuda. Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios.

Comment: Perfecto! funciono, MUCHAS GRACIAS!